# Codeigniter - Accessing json data on ajax post success

Tags: php, ajax, json

```
<label>Group Name</label>
   <select id="group" name="groupName">
     <option value="0">Select Group Name</option>
     <?php foreach ($userGroup as $item) { ?>
     <option value="<?= $item->notificationGroupID ?>"><?= $item->groupName ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
   </select>
<br></br>
```

This is the dropdown which i am populating from database and when i select any option in the dropdown it fires the following ajax post

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#group").change(function() {
  var group_ids = {"grp_ids" : $('#group').val()};

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: group_ids,
    url: "<?= base_url() ?>pushnotification_group_wise/group_wise_skyid",

    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);

         }
       });
     });
  });
```

now in the method "group_wise_skyid" inside a controller "pushnotification_group_wise" (as i am using codeigniter) the following codes are executing.

```
  public function group_wise_skyid()
  {

    if(isset($_POST['grp_ids']))
    {
      $skyid['sky_id'] = json_encode($this->pushnotification_model->get_group_eblskyids($_POST['grp_ids']));

      echo $skyid['sky_id'];
    }
```

which is calling a model function and returning some data which i am echoing. Now in the success function of the ajax post when i do console.log(data) i get the following in the console

```
    [{"mapID":"17","notificationGroupId":"3","eblskyId":"eblsky33"},{"mapID":"18","notificationGroupId":"3","eblskyId":"eblsky44"}]
```

which is in the json format. Now i need to access the data to be specific i need to access the

```
  notificationGroupId
  eblskyId
```

this two fields of the json string. Now should i store the whole json string in a variable then access somehow or how can i do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your method little bit:

```
$this->output
    ->set_content_type("application/json")
    ->set_output( json_encode($this->pushnotification_model->get_group_eblskyids($_POST['grp_ids'])) );
```

Instead of `echo $skyid['sky_id'];`

Now Accept the `JSON` data only you set the `dataType` in Ajax Request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: group_ids,
    url: "<?= base_url() ?>pushnotification_group_wise/group_wise_skyid",
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(i, data) {
            console.log('notificationGroupId - ', data.notificationGroupId);
            console.log('eblskyId - ', data.eblskyId);
        });
     }
   });
```

Handle it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{"mapID":"17","notificationGroupId":"3","eblskyId":"eblsky33"},{"mapID":"18","notificationGroupId":"3","eblskyId":"eblsky44"}]
```

This is an array of objects. This array consists of 2 objects.

I am assuming, name of this array is **data**

For accessing first object you can do this :

```
data[0].mapID will return "17"
data[0].notificationGroupId will return "3"
data[0].eblskyId will return "eblsky33"
```

Same for other indexes of data array

Comment: what i did is 
alert(data[0].mapID);

still showing undefined in the alert box.

Comment: alert(data[0].mapID); this statement must be inside of success: function(data){    }

Comment: exactly i have put the alert(data[0].mapID); inside the success:function(data){} but the result was undefined

Comment: Have you used Firebug for debugging your javascript code. Put a break point on that line and then go to console tab and type 'data' this will shows you how you can access the data indexes.

Answer (score 0):

use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) by this you can access all thing in data

in your case it is array of object

```js
var data = [{
  "mapID": "17",
  "notificationGroupId": "3",
  "eblskyId": "eblsky33"
}, {
  "mapID": "18",
  "notificationGroupId": "3",
  "eblskyId": "eblsky44"
}]


$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  alert(value.notificationGroupId);
  alert(value.eblskyId);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To save a s string

use **[toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)**

```
var str_data=data.toString()// you get as a string
```

Comment: looks like json array not an array

Comment: it doesn't work in the console window it says 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '124' in [{"mapID":"1","notificationGroupId":"1","eblskyId":"eblsky11"},{"mapID":"2","notificationGroupId":"1","eblskyId":"eblsky22"}]

Answer (score 0):

Your Response is an string not a JSON Object.

You have to use 
`data = JSON.Parse(data);`

Now you have a JSON object and then you can refer the answer given by @Rituraj ratan

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  alert(value.notificationGroupId);
  alert(value.eblskyId);
});
```